# Christmas card with tiny screen

Tags: lcd

I've just received a Christmas card with a tiny lcd that played a movie when opened. Sweet! Obviously, my first impulse was - time to load my own video! I hooked it up via a tiny usb port I found and I managed to open the video on it - it was titled "SOMETHING-MPEGx17.avi". Now, I tried loading an avi and then an mp4 onto it - neither played correctly. Does anyone have an idea of what to try next? Is there some way to archive an mp4 into an avi or something?

Thanks!

PS: Not sure if this is the right stackexchange site for this... Is it?

Comment: I don't know if there's a media-encoding SE site. Seems awful niche.

Comment: If its the process of working out what kind if file thats in it, SU might work. I do believe that if the card is cheap enough, its so totally a hacker's dream ;p

Comment: The format may turn out to be comparable to something used in a keychain player or similar minimal device - might even be the same chip inside.

Comment: Can you make a photo of the card with that display? Can you read any marks from any of the chips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An AVI file is just a *container.* Inside of it are multiple streams, each requiring their own codec to make sense of. For example, your AVI file could have an 8-bit h264 video stream and a MPEG layer 3 audio stream.

I hope you kept the original file! There are tools out there to show you what streams are in an AVI file (can't link without knowing your OS), so use one of these to figure out how the original file was encoded. Then (hopefully) you just need to encode your material in those formats and load it up (assuming it fits).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did keep the original. I have a PC - could you give me the link? Also, how hard will it be to then encode my video correctly? Can I literally do a "save as"?

Comment: I have no experience with PC-based encoding. Good news is that lots of encoders use PCs. So I'd start with Google, using terms like "windows avi decoder".

Comment: I would recommend [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net) for identifying what you need to encode to.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the encoding part of the question:

To see what format the original was in is easy - most media players have a "file properties" display where you can get this info. [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is one of the best and most versatile (free) players out there, and provides this info (and can re-encode files in different formats)

The codec info is under `Tools->Codec Information`
Here is an example screenshot:

[image: VLC Codec]

This is the information of the codecs used inside the container Mike mentions.

For (re)encoding, there are plenty of options:

VLC (mentioned above) - I found this a bit tricky to use for encoding, though it's certainly capable.

[WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) - this is probably the best free encoder out there (well the best I've found) and the one I'd recommend trying out. It's GUI based and simple to perform basic conversions, though there are *loads* of command line switches than can do all sorts of weird and wonderful things if you need to.

[DVDFab](http://www.dvdfab.com/video-converter.htm) - This is not free but you get a 30 day trial, and is probably the easiest to use and "just works" IME. Probably the one to go for if you only want to do this once.

Comment: Winff is a nice little front end for ffmpeg, which is quite simply one of the best multipurpose encoding software there is. If its a newish format, running an SVN version of ffmpeg might be a option for encoding.